# PHP can't pass variable to included file

Tags: php, variables, include

I tried to find a solution for this one:

**file1.php**

```
$name = "Jacob";
include ("file2.php");
```

**file2.php**

```
Hi there! <?php echo $name ?>
```

**Output**

```
Hi There! Notice: Undefined variable: name in /volume1/web/test/file2.php on line 9
```

Need help please ://

Comment: Just tried this and it works the way it should. You might try making $name a global variable but that brings other issues.

Comment: This works fine; indeed, it's how many PHP templating systems work at all.

Answer (score 10):

Your code works fine.

If you get that error your file1.php certainly does not define $name in the global scope.

Fyi, quoted from the docs:

> When a file is included, the code it
>   contains inherits the variable scope
>   of the line on which the include
>   occurs. Any variables available at
>   that line in the calling file will be
>   available within the called file, from
>   that point forward. However, all
>   functions and classes defined in the
>   included file have the global scope.

My testcase with php-5.3.3-pl1-gentoo(cli) in case it's a PHP bug in whatever version you are using - but I doubt that:

```
[thiefmaster@hades:~]> cat inc1.php
<?php
$name = 'bleh';
include('inc2.php');
?>
[thiefmaster@hades:~]> cat inc2.php
Hi there! <?php echo $name; ?>
[thiefmaster@hades:~]> php inc1.php
Hi there! bleh
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your URL ends in `file1.php` and not `file2.php` or some other file that includes `file2.php`. Also, try reducing both files to exactly what you posted here (plus a `<?php` at the beginning of `file1.php`) to rule out surrounding code.

Answer (score 1):

I sometimes get cuzzled (short for confuzzled) and forget to use the base file for checking a project online.

For instance, if using a base file called index.php with an include inc.php, make sure to launch index.php and not the include file.

The inc.php file will show errors in a browser because it's not linked to the index.php variables, whereas the index.php file contains both the variables and includes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed it like this:

```
$name = "Jacob";
include ("file2.php");
```

**file2.php**

```
$name = $name; //add this line
Hi there! <?php echo $name ?>
```

I can't explain why it should work like this.
Just it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code

```
global $name;    
$name = "Jacob";    
include ("file2.php");
```

** and inside file2.php

```
global $name;
echo "Hi there! ".$name;
```

I think that will work

Comment: That's not how `global` works, and unless the echo in file2 is in a function the `$name` is already in scope.

Comment: Sorry in php v5.3 the issue is different there is  a problem in passing variables to included file .. try it in that version .. u'll see what i meant

Answer (score 0):

I use an environment variable instead. It gets around this problem.

I.e.

`$_ENV["name"] = "Jacob";`

and inside `file2.php`

`echo $_ENV["name"];`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print/use `$name`variable then,You have to first declare that variable in `file2`as like `$name=""`,then You can easily use it,without declaring,You will get error of `Undefined Variable`.

Answer (score 0):

Note: If you are including a php file by a function like the code below, your variables which are not inside of the function are not defined in included file(s):

```
$myVar = array();
$myVar['v1'] = "name";
// and etc.

function including1($fva_1fname){
   include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . $fva_1fname);
   /*myVar is not defined in the included file*/
}

function including2($fva_2fname){
   global $myVar;
   include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . $fva_2fname);
   /*myVar is defined in the included file*/
}
```

Or you can use this function:

```
$includeThe = function($fva_2fname) use($myVar){
   include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/" . $fva_2fname);
   /*myVar is defined in the included file*/
}
```